# ¿Cómo puedo asignar a una variable el nombre que seleccione el usuario?

Tags: php, mysql, json, sql

Cuando el usuario vaya ingresando un nombre, el codigo le va a sugerir los que tiene en la base de datos que parean con lo que esta escribiendo. Ahora me gustaría que cuando el usuario encuentre entre las sugerencias el que desea utilizar y le de click, ese valor se asigne a una variable que voy a utilizar para hacer la busqueda del email de ese nombre seleccionado. Gracias por la ayuda que me puedan brindar.

```
<?php
    //Configuración
    $dbHost = 'localhost';
    $dbUsername = 'root';
    $dbPassword = '';
    $dbName = 'albizu';

    //Conexión
    $db = new mysqli($dbHost,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$dbName);

    //Obtiene el termino entrado
    $searchTerm = $_GET['term'];

    //Parea el termino entrado con los datos de la base de datos
    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE name LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' ORDER BY name ASC");
    while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data[] = $row['name'];
    }

    //Devuelve la busqueda
    echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

Comment: Pues utilizar la librería de Jquery para generar un Autocomplete que es lo que estas buscando te dejo el link. https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: Saludos, graciar por tu pronta respuesta. Estoy utilizando eso mismo en mi código HTML y hace la busqueda y todo perfecto. El problema es que estoy trancado porque luego que el usuario selecciona la sugerencia, no se como pasar ese valor a una variable para darle otro uso.

Comment: Supongo que el input en el que se selecciona el texto tendrá un nombre y/o id, esta parte del código no está, así que deberías poder recoger el valor del input, lo has intentado?